# Is there a another way to upload file with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

So I've been trying to automate a task of uploading a contacts file to a phone. The contact file can be uploaded in the web gui for the phone, I've managed to get it get to the page and select the right field but it just highlights it blue and doesn't upload the file as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsF84.png)

```
import time
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options =  Options()
options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = True;

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('xxxx')

### Logging in
user_box = driver.find_element("id", "idUsername")
user_box.send_keys('xxx')
pass_box = driver.find_element("id", "idPassword")
pass_box.send_keys('xxx')
login_button = driver.find_element("id", "idConfirm")
login_button.click()

### Waiting for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

### Uploading the file
chose_file = driver.find_element('xpath', '//button[contains(@onclick, "importxml")]')
chose_file.send_keys('file_location')

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Is there another way of uploading file other than using send.keys?

Below is the button in HTML if that helps

```
<td colspan="2">
            <input id="importxml" type="text" yltype="file" class="upload_file_input" readonly="readonly" filedesp="{'maxlength':'2MB', 'action':'contactxml', 'filetype':'contactxml'}" value="" onclick="YLFile.SelectFile('importxml')" />
            <button type="button" class="minWidth" id="btn_select" onclick="YLFile.SelectFile('importxml')"><script>T("Browse...")</script></button>
            <div>
            <button type="button" class="minWidth" id="btn_upload" name="LocalbtnImportXML" level="item" onclick="Contact.UploadXML()"><script>T("Import XML")</script></button>
            <button type="button" class="minWidth" id="btn_download" name="LocalbtnExportXML" level="item" onclick="Contact.DownloadFile('downloadxml')"><script>T("Export XML")</script></button>
            </div>
            <div id="file_widget" style="display:none;"> </div>
            <div id="upload_result" class="upload_result_box">
              <div class="upload_progress_bar" id="_progress_importxml" style="display:none;">
                <div id="progress_bar" class="progress_bar"></div><span id="progress_text">0%</span>
              </div>
              <div id="info_text_importxml" class="upload_result" style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
            <script> YLFile.InitUploadFiles("importxml"); </script>
          </td>
```

Comment: The best way is to inspect the request browser sends to the URL, then you can directly post your file to that URL obviously you have to check the auth request too, so that you can login, this will eliminate your selenium entirely

Comment: can u share url of the page?

Comment: @Himanshuman unfortunately it is a private page only accessible locally but I've updated the post with some of the HTML